# Implement FTP directory listing command (NLST) command in custom VB.NET FTP server

Tags: windows, vb.net, cmd, ftp

I am trying to program an FTP daemon using VB.NET. When the client sends the `NLST` command to get the files or folders in the path, the daemon sends each file or folder name one at a time (I have to write in each time `ls` to get the name of one file or folder only), I tried many methods and they did not work. Please help me, thank you.

This is the code I use:

```
Case "NLST"
    Dim str As New StringBuilder()
    Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(work_dir)

    For Each file In di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
        str.Append(file.Name).Append(Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    SendResponse(writer, str.ToString().TrimEnd)
```

When I run the program and type the `ls` command from the command prompt, it sends `NLST` command instead, which is very normal, but the problem is that my program sends one file every time I type the `ls` command in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is far from clear, I believe you are sending the "files" back to the *control* connection.

But the directory listing has to be sent to the *data* connection.
Read the FTP specification (RFC 959):
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959#page-8